# How can I write an fprintfn function that opens, appends, closes the file on each write, without getting an ObjectDisposedException?

Tags: f#, printf, dispose, objectdisposedexception

TL;DR: how to write a function like `fprintfn` that accesses and closes a file and behaves similar to `printf` family of functions, but won't throw an `ObjectDisposedException` on multiple arguments?

---

As a convenience embedded function, I found myself writing the following code, which worked for a while:

```
let fprintfn a b = 
    use handle = File.AppendText("somelogfile.log")
    printfn a b |> ignore   // write to stdout
    fprintfn handle a b     // write to logfile

// works
fprintfn "Here we are, %i years of age" 42

// throws ObjectDisposedException
fprintfn "Here we are, %i years of age in $i" 42 DateTime.Now.Year
```

The error is raised whether I use `use` or `using` and as soon as the number of arguments exceeds 2.

After some head-scratching, I concluded that the new `fprintfn` function above creates a closure as soon as I use it with more than one print format argument. Which seems to make sense to some extend, albeit a bit more hidden then in cases where you return a closure explicitly (i.e. returning an actual `fun x -> something` which accesses the `handle` variable).

Now the question is: how can I rewrite the above statement while retaining the convenience of the original `fprintfn` function use and syntax, without having it throw the `ObjectDisposedException`?

---

PS: A preferred way of writing the above function would be to use the following, which allows all `fprintfn` syntax, but that will throw the same exception already when you use a single print format argument.

```
let fprintfn a = 
    use handle = File.AppendText("somelogfile.log")
    printfn a |> ignore
    fprintfn handle a

fprintf "Test"              // works
fprintf "Test: %i" 42       // throws ODE
```

Comment: What about using kprintf?

Comment: @JohnPalmer, thought about it (perhaps not hard enough), but wouldn't that only move the issue further one level? In the end you still have to deal with the closures and opening/writing/disposing at the right spot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right that `fprintf` creates a continuation and returns it, so that by the time you call that continuation, the file is already closed.

But you can go one level deeper and use `kprintf`. It lets you provide [a "continuation"](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/printf.fs#L1326) - i.e. a function that receives the formatted string and does whatever with it.

```
let fprintfn a = 
  let doPrint s = 
    use handle = File.AppendText("somelogfile.log")
    printfn "%s" s
    fprintfn handle "%s" s

  kprintf doPrint a
```

And then, of course, you can simplify that a bit by using `File.AppendAllText`:

```
let fprintfn a = 
  let doPrint s = 
    File.AppendAllText("somelogfile.log", s + "\n")
    printfn "%s" s
  kprintf doPrint a
```